Error in custom function with group_by and summarise in dplyr in r
I try to write a custom function with dplyr::group_by and summarise.
but always error, "row.names" length.
I simplify the data and code, and find the reason. here is the data and code:
set.seed(123)
df = data.frame(
  Group = c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B", "B"),
  Con = runif(11, min = 10, max = 60),
  YN = rbinom(11, 1, 0.5)
)

cf = function(x, y){
  df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  summarise(median = median(x),
            n = n(),
            YN_n = sum(y),
            YN_perc = sum(y)/n()*100,
            CI = binom.confint(sum(y), n(),
                               conf.level = 0.95, methods = "exact"))
}

cf(df$Con, df$YN)

I found the error is caused by the different length of Group A and B.
If I change Group to 5 A and 5 B, it works.
But my actual data has different values in different groups, how to fix this problem?

! could not find function "binom.confint"

Anyway your summarise() call is not fed anything group specific, since you pass the full columns to your cf() call, call  cf(Con, YN) and replace x by {{ x }} and y by {{ y }} in your function's body and it might work (see https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#indirection)

I think you want to mutate the call to binom.conf, and add .groups="drop" to the summarise.

@moodymudskipper , I modified my code with Edward's answer, and it works.  And your {{x}} suggestion is very important to me. Thank you!

You need to put the call to binom.conf in a mutate , and add .groups="drop" to the summarise function. I also added a data argument to the function. (while also acknowledging moodymudskipper's embrace)
cf = function(data, x, y){
  data %>%
    group_by(Group) %>%
    summarise(median = median({{x}}),
              n = n(),
              YN_n = sum({{y}}),
              YN_perc = YN_n/n*100, .groups="drop") %>%
    mutate(CI = binom.confint(YN_n, n, conf.level = 0.95, methods = "exact"))
}


require(binom)

cf(df, Con, YN)

  Group median     n  YN_n YN_perc CI$method    $x    $n $mean $lower $upper
  <chr>  <dbl> <int> <int>   <dbl> <chr>     <int> <int> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 A       49.4     5     3      60 exact         3     5   0.6  0.147  0.947
2 B       37.0     6     3      50 exact         3     6   0.5  0.118  0.882

